# Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: react-native

while creating a new project in react-native i face this problem i m set path of android sdk and java sdk too .my old projects runs but while building a new project i get this error .... HELP !! i'm new to react-native

Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (`cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug`)...

> Unzipping C:\Users\Sanam
>   Gurung.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.5.1-all\42vjebfdws9pjts3l4bouoq0p\gradle-3.5.1-all.zip
>   to C:\Users\Sanam
>   Gurung.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.5.1-all\42vjebfdws9pjts3l4bouoq0p
>   Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in
>   opening zip file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your gradle-3.5.1-all file is corrupted delete it from

```
C:\Users\Sanam Gurung.gradle\.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

and then just run

```
react-native run-android
```

Comment: thnks a lots of lot  sir, tht helped me get past tht error bt i still got an error on node  
                                                                                                                           Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `D:\rncourse\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map

Comment: downgrade your react-native version to 0.55.4 if you are on 0.56.0 and also downgrade babel-preset-react-native to 4.0.0 if you are on version 5 

    npm install react-native@0.55.4 babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0 --save

Comment: npm WARN notice Due to a recent security incident, all user tokens have been invalidated. Please see https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/dn7c1fgrr7ng for more details. To generate a new token, visit https://www.npmjs.com/settings/~/tokens or run "npm login".
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: -@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sanam Gurung\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-18T09_05_53_109Z-debug.log

Comment: sir it gives an error to roll back says smth about token !

Comment: i recently made an account for npm and refuses to input password when runned in cmd npm login

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory

Comment: please share package.json of your project

Comment: {
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: this one is my old project that runs sir                                                                                  - {
  "name": "albums",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Comment: in your new project just change two things  first react-native version from  "react-native": "0.56.0" to "react-native": "0.55.4" and second change  "babel-preset-react-native": "5"  to "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0" after making these changes in your package.json then just run 

    npm install
that's all

Comment: thnk you very very much sir tht helped ur genius !!

Comment: sir,  one more thing do i need to do this method every time ? it worked a wonder though ,,,

Comment: actually it's a problem with react native's current version 0.56.0 as it's really buggy and unstable at the moment while it's getting you can use a workaround for making new project ,you should also specify the react native version like

    react-native init ProjectName --version react-native@0.55.4

Comment: thnks a lot !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!